# Help with ISBN Checker written in Java

Tags: java

I am currently working on a homework assignment written in java where he program is supposed to read in a text file of ISBN numbers and check if they are valid, and then print out the list of valid, or invalid numbers sorted in lexicographical order (ignoring the dashes).
Here are all my classes:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ISBN isbn = new ISBN();
        ISBNReader reader = new ISBNReader();
        ISBNProcessor processor = new ISBNProcessor(reader, isbn);
        ISBNPrinter printer = new ISBNPrinter(processor);


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        reader.setFileName("isbn.txt");

        reader.setISBNNumbers();
        processor.processISBNNumbers();
        printer.printISBNNumbers();
    }

}

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ISBNReader {

    private ISBN isbn = new ISBN();
    private ArrayList<ISBN> inISBN = new ArrayList<ISBN>();
    private int[] isbnNums = new int[13];
    private String fileName = "";
    private String next = "";

    public ISBNReader(){
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName){
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileName(){
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setISBNNumbers(){
        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(fr);
            while(in.hasNextLine()){
                next = in.next();
                isbn.setISBNString(next);
                inISBN.add(isbn);
            }
            in.close();

            FileReader frNums = new FileReader(fileName);
            Scanner scanNums = new Scanner(frNums);

            while(scanNums.hasNextInt()){
                for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
                    isbnNums[i] = scanNums.nextInt();
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < inISBN.size(); i++){
                    inISBN.get(i).setISBNNumbers(isbnNums);
                }
                scanNums.nextLine();
            }
            scanNums.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(ISBNReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<ISBN> getISBNNumbers(){
        return inISBN;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ISBNProcessor {

    private ISBNReader reader = new ISBNReader();
    private ISBN isbn = new ISBN();
    private String numOnlyString;
    private ArrayList<ISBN> inISBN = new ArrayList<ISBN>();
    private ArrayList<ISBN> validISBNs = new ArrayList<ISBN>();
    private ArrayList<ISBN> invalidISBNs = new ArrayList<ISBN>();
    private boolean isNumOnly;
    private int[] isbnNums = new int[13];

    ISBNProcessor(ISBNReader reader, ISBN isbn){
        this.reader = reader;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        inISBN = reader.getISBNNumbers();
    }

    public void processISBNNumbers(){
        for(int i = 0; i <inISBN.size();i++){
            isbnNums = inISBN.get(i).getISBNNumbers();
            if(isbnNums[12] == (10 - ((isbnNums[0] + 3*isbnNums[1] +isbnNums[2] + 3*isbnNums[3] +
                                       isbnNums[4] + 3*isbnNums[5] +isbnNums[6] + 3*isbnNums[7] +
                                       isbnNums[8] + 3*isbnNums[9] +isbnNums[10] + 3*isbnNums[11])
                                       % 10) % 10)){
                validISBNs.add(inISBN.get(i));
            }
            else{
              invalidISBNs.add(inISBN.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ISBN> getValidISBNNumbers(){
        return validISBNs;
    }

    public ArrayList<ISBN> getInvalidISBNNumbers(){
        return invalidISBNs;
    }

}

public class ISBNPrinter {

    private ISBNReader reader = new ISBNReader();
    private ISBN isbn = new ISBN();
    private ISBNProcessor processor = new ISBNProcessor(reader, isbn);;

    ISBNPrinter(ISBNProcessor processor){
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public void printISBNNumbers(){
        System.out.println("Valid");
        for(int i = 0; i < processor.getValidISBNNumbers().size(); i++){
            System.out.println(processor.getValidISBNNumbers().get(i).getISBNString());
        }

        System.out.println("Invalid");
        for(int i = 0; i < processor.getInvalidISBNNumbers().size(); i++){
            System.out.println(processor.getInvalidISBNNumbers().get(i).getISBNString());
        }
    }
}

public class ISBN {

    private int[] isbnNumbers = new int[13];
    private String isbnString;
    private String trash;


    public ISBN(int[] isbn){
        this.isbnNumbers = isbn;
    }

    ISBN() {
    }

    public void setISBNNumbers(int[] isbn){
        this.isbnNumbers = isbn;
    }

    public int[] getISBNNumbers(){
        return this.isbnNumbers;
    }

    public void setISBNString(String isbnString){
        this.isbnString = isbnString;
    }

    public String getISBNString(){
        return this.isbnString;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when i go to print out the invalid and valid ISBN numbers, it just prints out the the last ISBN number repeatedly. Like this:

```
Valid
Invalid
978-04-2135-828-8
978-04-2135-828-8
978-04-2135-828-8
978-04-2135-828-8
978-04-2135-828-8
978-04-2135-828-8
978-04-2135-828-8
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The text file looks like this:

```
978-04-2135-828-8
978-03-2135-828-8
97A-03-2135-828-8
978-1408819899
978-0-13-216675-1
978-0-13-601722-6
978-04-2135-828-8
```

Any Suggestions or solutions? My program is due midnight tonight (central time) and i'm really struggling so any help would be great!

Thanks!

Method I deleted from ISBN:

```
public void stringToNumbers(){
        for(int i = 0; i < isbnString.length(); i++){
            if(isbnString.charAt(i) != '-' &&
               (Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 1 ||Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 2 ||
               Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 3 ||Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 4 ||
               Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 5 ||Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 6 ||
               Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 7 ||Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 8 ||
               Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 9 ||Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i,i+1)) == 0)){

                    isbnNumbers[i] = (int) Integer.parseInt(isbnString.substring(i));
            }
            else{
                return;

            }

        }
    }
```

I deleted this method and added the second while loop but now it seems to be a necessity. Anybody know an efficient way to transfer the numbers without the dashes? The above method wouldn't work.

EDIT:
Here is the new method that seems to work until it hits a dash.

```
public void stringToNumbers(){
        for(int i = 0; i < isbnString.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(isbnString.charAt(i)))
                    isbnNumbers[i] = (isbnString.charAt(i)-48);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger?

Comment: It seems a bit over-engineered.

Comment: i have tried but i couldn't figure anything out from it. Sorry kind of a noob here

Comment: anyway you would suggest simplifying it?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            next = in.next();
            isbn.setISBNString(next);
            inISBN.add(isbn);
        }
```

You're changing the isbn String in an ISBN object and adding it to your list, but since you never create a new ISBN object, you're adding the same object to the list over and over again, each time changing it's isbn String. But since they're all the items added to the list are the exact same ISBN object all have the same isbn String. On the last go around through the loop, all of the items in the list will have a reference to the last isbn String added.

The solution is to create a new ISBN object inside of this while loop each time you want to add a new ISBN object with a unique String into the list. So there should be a call to

```
isbn = new ISBN();
```

somewhere near the top of the while loop.

Something like,

```
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            next = in.next();
            ISBN isbn = new ISBN(); // added
            isbn.setISBNString(next);
            inISBN.add(isbn);
        }
```

When you see something happening like this in your program, look for just this sort of problem -- not creating a new object when necessary. The other common cause of this is inappropriate use of the static specifier.

**Edit 1**
Regarding your recent post and your desire to check if a char is numeric or not, the Character class has a method, isDigit(char ch) that does this for you.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix the input problem. Now it seems that it won't put the numbers into the array... not sure what is going on there.

Comment: Do some debugging with either a debugger or println statements to see what's going on.

Comment: i added a println statment to print out all the array numbers for all the isbn's and it seems to be printing out just zero's

Comment: it seems to be skipping over the second while loop? looks like i need to reset the scanner to the beginning. is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the 2nd while loop? Why do you need another Scanner object to scan in the data from the file when you've already got that very same data held in a list of the ISBN objects?

Comment: I was using it to retrieve just the numbers, because i couldn't figure out how to change a string with dashes and letters into just a the number without the dashes, to check it through the equation i was given. So if i do that, it would eliminate the need for the second while loop

Comment: Shouldn't that be a method inside of ISBN, that an ISBN object does automatically when it gets a String? Then you would only need one while loop.

Comment: I actually had it as a method in ISBN before, but i couldn't get it to work. i couldn't figure out a proper if statement to get rid of the dashes so i changed it to this, but this way obviously isn't going to work haha

Comment: alright i added it to the question. I couldn't figure out how to see if the character being inspected was a int or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see **Edit 1** in my answer above.

Comment: Alright i got the method to work but the for loop exits out after it hits a dash? Am i missing something simple? If I am i apologize, this thing is just starting to stress me out, really wish i would have started earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the program in a very complex and long way.
Here is a shorter and better way to do the same :-

```
import java.io.*;
public class ISBN
{
   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
   {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       int n,r,d = 0; int count = 0; int k = 11;
       System.out.println("Enter the ISBN number :");
       n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       while (n!=0)
       {
           r = n%10;
           k -= 1;
           count++;
           d += (k*r);
           n = n/10;
       }
       if (count == 10)
       {
           if (d%11 == 0)    System.out.println("Legal ISBN number");

           else    System.out.println("Illegal ISBN number");
       }

       else     System.out.println("Illegal ISBN number");
    }
}
```